# touchesMoved touches.first!.view remains the same, if I move a finger out of view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit, touch

I have a problem with `touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)` function. More specifically - touches.first!.view property.
I need to know the tag of view that user is pointing at. But when I drag finger out of view bounds, touches.first!.view value does not change.

This is what I am doing:
[image]

I have this code to print out selected view's tag and background color:

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    print("\(touches.first!.view!.backgroundColor), View tag: " + String(touches.first!.view!.tag))
}
```

But I expect to get printed out is `UIExtendedGrayColorSpace 1 1, View tag: 0`, but instead of this I get `<UIDynamicSystemColor: 0x600000820b40; name = systemGroupedBackgroundColor>, View tag: 5`. This means, that even if I drag my cursor from one view, I still get the first clicked view from `touches.first!.view`.

How can I get the ***current*** selected view?

Comment: Yes, this is the intended behavior. Re solution, it depends upon what you want to do, but you can just convert the point to the coordinate space of the super view and then see if its _bounds_ contain the point. Or, alternatively, disable user interaction with the gray rectangle, capture the touches in the white view’s coordinate space, and if then see if the gray square’s _frame_ containers the point (because those are both in the coordinate system of the white view, no coordinate translations are needed).

Comment: @Rob Thank you! I think I understand what you said, but I don't know how to write this. I would really appreciate if you could write a full answer.

Comment: I also have multiple of these gray squares (about 25).

Comment: Use `hitTest` to ask what view contains the given point. See https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/66e806a9e05e7886cff64d4bd1b889104bae49fe/bk2ch05p210hitTesting/ch18p551hitTesting/ViewController.swift for an example (uses a gesture recognizer but that's irrelevant to the use of `hitTest`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer based on Rob's comment above

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)
    if let touch = touches.first {
        if ( !self.grayUIView.frame.contains(touch.location(in: self.grayUIView)) ){
        return

        }else {
        //still in current view - process with your logic

        }
    }
}
```